# WebSphere Message Broker MQMD Report

Tags: websphere, message, ibm-mq, messagebroker

When I set MQMD.Expiry and MQM.Report (= MQRO_EXPIRATION_WITH_FULL_DATA) in Message Broker, where do messages go if they expire?

Should I catch them in the MQInput node?

If so, how do I differentiate between these and other errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

You have to set the MQMD.ReplyToQ in the message header.  That way it will return to that queue once it expire.  (Keep in mind a message is only thrown out when an MQGET is performed on that queue

(Just moving this from comments in case any misses it.)